# Android: Other user can't feed/share through my Facebook app

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created Facebook app (for testing purpose) and changed in public mode. I can able to feed and share through my App. but other user can't do the same, they getting error like

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application
     to perform this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I have add the permission "publish_actions" in permission also (I used graph API).

When I first login in confirmation page show the message like

> The following permission have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: publish_actions (submit them for review or learn more.)

Please share details about configuration steps of app in developer page.

My code here:

login function

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS ={"publish_actions","email"};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void login()
    {

        sh = getSharedPreferences("mydata", 0);
        String access_token = sh.getString("access_token", null);
        Long expire = sh.getLong("expire", 0);
        if(access_token!=null)
            fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        if(expire!=0)
            fb.setAccessExpires(expire);
        if(!fb.isSessionValid())
        fb.authorize(this,PERMISSIONS,new DialogListener(){

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Editor e = sh.edit();
                e.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken().toString());
                e.putLong("expire", fb.getAccessExpires());
                e.commit();
                Log.d("Token", fb.getAccessToken().toString());
                Log.d("expire",Long.toString(fb.getAccessExpires()));
                Profile();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }

//for image post

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void ImageandTextupload()
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, b);
        data = b.toByteArray();

        Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param.putByteArray("picture", data);
        param.putString("message", "this is test post");
        param.putString("description", "description");
        param.putString("caption", "caption");
        param.putString("name", "anand");
        param.putString("link","http://google.com");
        sh = getSharedPreferences("mydata", 0);
        String access_token = sh.getString("access_token", null);
        param.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, access_token);

        asyn.request("/"+user_id+"/feed", param, "POST",new RequestListener(){

            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Photo_response",response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }},null);

    }
```

Comment: Downvoted with regret, as a good answer came in on the same day, and you did not reply, vote or accept.

Answer (score 1):

Since April 2014, most permissions (including `publish_actions`) have to get approved in order to work for other users. See this link for information about the process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

It is also important to take a look at the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog